# Magit-status failing on git directory

Tags: git, emacs, cygwin, magit

I am facing an issue with the Magit on Emacs 25.1.1. When I try to do magit-status on the git directory I get the following error: 
apply: Setting current directory: Invalid argument, c:/configfiles^M/

I am not able to understand why the ctrl-m is getting appended to the directory. When I check the same on the cygwin-shell I dont see this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

BackTrace is below:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Setting current directory" "Invalid argument" "c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/emulator\015/")
  call-process("C:/cygwin64/usr/libexec/git-core/git.exe" nil (t nil) nil "--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "config" "--list" "-z")
  apply(call-process "C:/cygwin64/usr/libexec/git-core/git.exe" nil (t nil) nil ("--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "config" "--list" "-z"))
  process-file("C:/cygwin64/usr/libexec/git-core/git.exe" nil (t nil) nil "--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "config" "--list" "-z")
  apply(process-file "C:/cygwin64/usr/libexec/git-core/git.exe" nil (t nil) nil ("--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "config" "--list" "-z"))
  magit-process-file("C:/cygwin64/usr/libexec/git-core/git.exe" nil (t nil) nil "--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "config" "--list" "-z")
  apply(magit-process-file "C:/cygwin64/usr/libexec/git-core/git.exe" nil (t nil) nil ("--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "config" "--list" "-z"))
  magit-git-insert("config" "--list" "-z")
  apply(magit-git-insert ("config" "--list" "-z"))
  magit-git-items("config" "--list" "-z")
  magit-config-get-from-cached-list("magit.extension")
  magit-get-all("magit.extension")
  magit-load-config-extensions()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook special-mode-hook magit-mode-hook magit-status-mode-hook)
  apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook special-mode-hook magit-mode-hook magit-status-mode-hook))
  run-mode-hooks(magit-status-mode-hook)
  magit-status-mode()
  magit-mode-setup-internal(magit-status-mode nil)
  magit-mode-setup(magit-status-mode)
  magit-status-internal("c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/emulator/src/ericsson/appexamples/handoverAgent/")
  magit(nil ((1 . 6) (("c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/emulator\015/" . magit-toplevel)) (("c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/" "rev-parse" "--git-dir")) (("c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/" "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel")) (("c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/emulator/src/ericsson/appexamples/handoverAgent/" . magit-toplevel) . "c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/emulator\015/") (("c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/emulator/src/ericsson/appexamples/handoverAgent/" "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel") . "/cygdrive/c/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/emulator\015")))
  funcall-interactively(magit nil ((1 . 6) (("c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/emulator\015/" . magit-toplevel)) (("c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/" "rev-parse" "--git-dir")) (("c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/" "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel")) (("c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/emulator/src/ericsson/appexamples/handoverAgent/" . magit-toplevel) . "c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/emulator\015/") (("c:/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/emulator/src/ericsson/appexamples/handoverAgent/" "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel") . "/cygdrive/c/users/evijyaj/DropBox/MANA/emulator\015")))
  call-interactively(magit record nil)
  command-execute(magit record)
  #f(compiled-function (cmd) #<bytecode 0x2bdeeb5>)("magit")
  ivy-call()
```

Comment: It may have been set accidentally. Try `M-x cd` to some (legal) directory and try the `magit-status` again. If that does not work, then do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, try again and add the resulting backtrace to your question here.

Comment: Added backtrace to the message

Comment: Well we can see that the path with the `^M` suffix is in the `cache` argument for `magit-status`.  I *imagine* it will regenerate the same, but you could see whether `M-x magit-zap-caches` changes anything.  Does `M-: (magit-toplevel)` after that give you the same value?

Comment: The "magit-zap-caches" did not help. When I evaluate (magit-toplevel), I see the ^M appended to the git path.